# Solve system of differential equations with time dependent variable in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations, stochastic-process

I have following system of differential equations

```
x'(t) = (10+σ(t))(y(t)-x(t))
y'(t) = ρx(t)-y(t)-x(t)z(t)
z'(t) = x(t)y(t)-βz(t)
```

where ρ and β are constants and σ is Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. In fact, the system is Lorenz system embedded in stochastic environment.

Solution of σ is

σ<sub>t</sub>=σ<sub>0</sub>e<sup>-αt</sup>+γe<sup>-αt</sup>∫<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup>e<sup>αs</sup>dW<sub>s</sub>

and I think I can solve it in Python like below

```
t_max = 1
n = 1000
t, dt = np.linspace(0, t_max, n, endpoint=False, retstep=True)
dW = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(n)
alpha = 1
gamma = 1
sigma = sigma_0 * np.exp(-alpha * t) + gamma * np.exp(-alpha * t) * np.cumsum(np.exp(alpha * t) * dW)
```

Now given `sigma` as above, if it is correct, how can I get the solution for the system?

Comment: Now make the function table (t,sigma) into an interpolation function and use that in the ODE function.

Comment: do you want a symbolic or numeric solution?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Should `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` be enough? Or is there more "accurate" method of interpolation?

Comment: @anon01 I want numeric solution so I can experiment with effects of α and γ to the whole system.

Comment: Yes, that is the advanced option with several methods to select from in the background. Piecewise linear should be sufficient, over-smoothing with piecewise cubics could have strange effects. Or take a dedicated SDE solver that solves for all 4 dynamic components simultaneously.